# How to get Application Name To Call from PID in Mac AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

There is a script that lets you resize any app in mac. This is the code:

```
set theApp to "Application Name" 
set appHeight to 1080
set appWidth to 1920

    tell application "Finder"
    set screenResolution to bounds of window of desktop
end tell

set screenWidth to item 3 of screenResolution
set screenHeight to item 4 of screenResolution

tell application theApp
      activate
      reopen
      set yAxis to (screenHeight - appHeight) / 2 as integer
      set xAxis to (screenWidth - appWidth) / 2 as integer
      set the bounds of the first window to {xAxis, yAxis, appWidth + xAxis, appHeight + yAxis}
      end tell
```

I want to change the size of a java application opened by a launcher. When I insert the name of any app, it works. However when I insert the name of the app that I want to resize it doesn't work. I know the process id of the app that I want to resize. Is there a way I can change this line `set theApp to "Application Name"` to use PID instead of Application name?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all **apps** are **AppleScript** *scriptable* and some that are do not support the `bounds` *property*, they use `position`  *property* and `size` *property*.  Also, sometimes you'll need **System Events** to *position* and *size* an **app's** *window*.

I use a *keyboard shortcut* assigned in [**FastScripts**](https://red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) with the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* to automatically adjust the *frontmost* app's *window*. You can adjust the *code* to suite your needs.

If the *frontmost* **app** can't use the `bounds` *property* it silently *errors*, and then **System Events** does it.

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    set frontmostProcess to name of process 1 whose frontmost is true
end tell

try
    tell application frontmostProcess
        set bounds of window 1 to {0, 22, 1136, 844}
    end tell
on error
    tell application "System Events" to tell application process frontmostProcess
        set position of window 1 to {0, 22}
        set size of window 1 to {1136, 822}
    end tell
end try
```

<sup>Note: I am not affiliated with the developer of FastScript, just a satisfied user. It's also **free** for the first ten *keyboard shortcuts*.</sup>